# Web API query options custom filter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I am trying to support `IQueryable` controllers but there is this problem I cant find a way to fix. suppouse I need to filter the next list of words

- Apple
- Arizona
- Automobile
- A

Now my clients have an autocomplete textbox that shows possible options. It makes a query similar to this

```
"api/RandomWods?$filter=substringof('" + input + "',Name)&$top=3"
```

When input is `A` I am not able to get `A` record as an option, because there are already 3 records that contains `A`.

**Is there a better query to support this?**

**Can I build a custom filter function?**

something like

```
"api/Currencies?$filter=bestmatches('" + input + "'),Name)&$top=3
```

then define bestmatches as a server side method.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but startswith would have the same issue as you are returning the first 3 records. A seems to be the 4th from what you have posted.

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath True I missed that

Comment: since you are returning top 3, cant you just increment the top values, or actually order it by. If you order it by, the value A would be the first.

Comment: It would work if I order by name Length, do you know how I do that?

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options  - (http://localhost/Products?$orderby=Name)

Comment: @SurgeonofDeath that will create a new problem, now I wont see the result if it is not alphabetically in the firts 3 positions. this would work If I could `/Products?$orderby=length(Name)` but that is not supported, but I guess is the best I can do. thanks for your help

Comment: Iqueryable has OrderBy option. Why dont you just return it inside your code? OrderBy(x=>x.SomeProperty.length)